# Redirect traffic of Google Talk for Android

Tags: android, iptables, google-talk

I know Google Talk for Android tries to connect to mtalk.google.com:5228 (or port 5223 or port 5222) but when I'm connected to University Wifi I can't use gTalk because all outgoing connection to port 5228 (etc.) are blocked. I know also that the Google Talk services are accessible trought port mtalk.google.com:443. [Correct me if I'm wrong].

Can I redirect all my outgoing traffic to mtalk.google.com:5228 to mtalk.google.com:443 ? Maybe using an app? Or using iptables? And how can I do?

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully someone else will have a solution, but it seems like Google Talk in the browser automatically does this (hence, service available through 443), but the Android version only uses 5228.

[This thread](http://code.google.com/p/miranda/issues/detail?id=120) suggest it may be a fallback-only scenario, so you might run into problems with redirection even if you can redirect the traffic on the phone.

[This issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10576) suggests, once again, that the 443 port is only available for the browser version of Google Talk.

Finally, while it isn't absolutely a reliable user, [here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/talk/J5Z3wluo8fA) is a little more support for the possibility that Android GTalk just outright can't use port 443.

Comment: I am using port 443 with pidgin, so the suggestion that it is only for the browser is wrong.

Comment: I don't think that I suggested the port was only for the browser.  All I said was that only the browser version of the *product* Google Talk uses 443.  That being said, this may have changed now.  If you have any other information I encourage you to submit an answer or an edit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are many ways to do it.
There are stand alone proxy apps or apps that provide the service as well.

One simple solution that can just work is to use Orbot: Tor on Android.

Another solution that does not related to tor https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mgranja.autoproxy_lit

Since you mentioned Iptables you can also try ProxyDroid but you'll need a proxy server from out there.

BTW.what android version are you using? I think that gtalk moved to https on recent versions.